# Android Things {AppName} has stopped - get logs

Tags: android, android-things, android-things-console

I'm running a build from the Android Things Console built with several custom apks

One of the apps is failing with "{AppName}" has stopped. Open app again" The cause appears isolated to only one Configuration.

I'm trying to get to root cause, normally I would run "adb logcat" to view full details with android. Is adb logcat support with Android Things build? Is a mechanism such as logcat available in Android Things when built with a build from the Android Things Console? If not, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

ADB is available on development images of Android Things, not on production builds. You can change which one in the console. You can also add crash reporting tools like [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/?&gclid=Cj0KCQiAgMPgBRDDARIsAOh3uyK3hBUNyRRZWblHTEpn3DBN-Ra0BD_Y83-Pd3WKGCMNj4LhgerDKs4aAnkPEALw_wcB) which will provide crash reports for you.

Comment: See the docs for more details about production vs. development builds of Android Things - https://developer.android.com/things/console/build

Comment: Thank you. I'm only having "Development" available as an option but the article does confirm that I should be able to use adb. I will pursue that route.

Comment: Article also mentions I can use a Serial debug console. https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi